# What are the alternate ways of HREF in <asp:Button>, except OnClientClick to call inline div?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, css, href

I created a hidden `<div>` on same page and call it with `href="#"` and it's working perfect, BUT when I use same code in ASP.net due to some JavaScript or not sure why it is not working. First time when page loads it's working but after then due to some undesirable side effects it's not working it's strange...!!!

Is there any other / alternate way to call hidden div on same page with or without # instead href. I also tried following both ways:

```
OnClientClick="location.href='#inline_content2"
OnClientClick="#inline_content2;"
```

However, It works but it shows div wihtout content :(

Following is the original code which is working fine in plain HTML only:

```
href="#inline_content"
```

So how to call my div on same page which is #inline_content without href?

Comment: can you put your html

Answer (score 0):

Set href="javascript:void(0);"
And keep the other things as usual.

Comment: Thanks @Shekhar, but em not good in JavaScript so i appreciated if you could provide me the code example?

Comment: @mknayab If you can put your html which you are trying only I can give you a full answer. the above code will stop from postback if you will click on a link.

Comment: Basically it is in ASP.net and lots of files are in relation so I can give you complete code of particular file but that's not works without all relations etc... Hope you understand, but here is the HTML Code / Line where I need a change:

<asp:Button ID="btn142" runat="server" Text="Add New Client" CssClass="btn142 inline" href="#inline_content" />

Now how do i set href="javascript:void(0);" on href="#inline_content" in above line?

Comment: @mknayab what do you want to do with button. It don't have a href property.

Comment: I need to call hidden dive on same page through button; but it is working with href even it is not a property of button but working fine. I only need to stop postback on page because href="#inline_content" creates a postback.

Comment: Yes @Shekhar i want to show following div 'inline_content': 
<div style='display:none'>
  <div id='inline_content' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
  <div>content</div>
</div>